# Running "ubuntu-support-status" throws an exception

Tags: command-line, crash, execute-command, support

I was reading on [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) that running

```
ubuntu-support-status
```

Will "...print the exact status of your system."

However, if I run that command, it crashes and throws an exception. Here's the stacktrace:

```
dev@dev-Ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-support-status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 133, in <module>
    pkg.name, support_tag)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-support-status", line 49, in get_maintenance_status
    raise Exception("No date tag found")
Exception: No date tag found
```

And I got this GUI popup:
[image]

I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-apt/+bug/1503979), [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/829200) and [this on Launchpad....](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/622489)

I am using 14.04 x64

Comment: +1 Nice one. I didn't know about `ubuntu-support-status`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, thanks to @cl-netbox and @Videonauth, I have solved the problem.

Apparently, even though `python-apt` was up to date, some other package (that it probably depends on) wasn't, and that was the cause of the issue.

Simply running

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Fixed the issue.